# Does different bulbs in one circuit lead to shorter lifespan?

Tags: watts, lamp, home-installation

I had a conversation with my family regarding lifespans of bulbs. They claimed that they had observed that when different wattage bulbs are plugged in the same hanging light, the bulbs would die sooner. Specifically, they noticed that in a 3-way arrangement with one bulb of different wattage, that one lamp would be the first to die. That could also be the case in different arrangements.

I didn't believe them and I put it down to the quality of the lamps tested, since none of the physics or maths I know would explain it. However, I cannot test the theory because it would take too much time and (electrical) energy. Am I missing something?

Is it possible that the bulbs would die sooner if connected in the fashion described? Could some malfunction of the hanging light be the cause?

Necessary info: I live in Europe so the mains voltage is 230V/50Hz AC and, given that the rest of the bulbs would stay on, the lamps are wired in parallel. The bulbs were probably incandescent bulbs.

I am asking because I am going to change some dead bulbs so hopefully the answers will help me on whether I have to make sure that the new LED lamps have the same wattage as the old or the other ones. If I don't have to, I might as well use some bulbs I have lying around.

I know those are a lot of questions so
***Thanks a lot!***

P.S.: I did search the web and only found [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/231586/two-bulbs-of-different-wattage-in-one-ac-circuit) but it doesn't cover anything about the lifespan of the bulbs. Also, if this is not the correct site, notify me of the right one.

Comment: Sorry, but questions about the use of consumer products (such as lightbulbs) are off-topic for this site.

Comment: The point is, as the lamps are different, they have a different lifespan. Maybe they are from different manufacturer, or wildly different circuit as they are different wattage. Thus they cannot be compared. Higher wattage lamps may run hotter and hotter may have shorter lifespan due to heat.

Comment: From what they described, the difference in the lifespan was too much from what would be expected, without comparing to other bulbs. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three lamps will have identical supply voltage as they are in the one fixture. They don't know about each other and each will draw the current they require based on their individual resistances. Their lifespan will be the same as if they were in separate rooms of the house unless there is an additional factor such as excessive temperature due to the three bulbs being in the one enclosure, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That it is what I believed and those were exactly my arguments.

Comment: OK. You've won the arguement. Now go and wash the dishes after the family meal so you don't get big-headed! Tip: wait a day or two to encourage others to answer and then "accept" the best one to indicate to the system that your question has been answered - otherwise it keep popping up on the home page.

Comment: Please don't be rude. Also, I had no intention of keeping the question without an accepted answer. Edit before further answers: I cleaned the dishes earlier.

Comment: I wasn't being rude. Sorry if the humour missed its mark.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it

Answer (score 1):

Since the supply voltage for household incandescent bulbs is fixed, the resistance of the bulbs filament varies with the wattage. Low wattage bulbs have the highest resistance. This is acomplished during manufacture by using thinner wire for the filament. That means that low wattage bulbs are more delicate than high wattage bulbs. With everything else being equal, you could expect low wattage bulbs to fail sooner than high wattage bulbs especially if they are subject to vibration.